`Needs` versus `<<`
Is it possible that loading an .m package via <<ReactionKinetics produces errors the second time it is loaded, while Needs["ReactionKinetics"] doesn't?
I have two packages which I reload several times during the session. One is .wl, and works fine via <<, but the other one is .m, and produces errors unless  Needs is used.
In summary, is Needs always  preferable to << ?

It depends on whether you're developing or just using the package. Why are you reloading the packages?

I am using the .m package and developing the .wl one. Reloading is probably superfluous (silly?), but I like to stuff lots in the first cell, to minimize clicking

From the docs for Needs: "Needs["context`"]
loads an appropriate file if the specified context is not already in $Packages." Get always loads the file.

I always use Get never Needs. Feels more safe to me. This way I do not need to wonder or guess if my changes in the .m file were read or not each time.

I develop a .wl package, and there you are forced to run the package each time you modify, so this issue does not arise. But, interesting to know, thanks
